# Allure JS protractor-cucumber-framework cucumberOpts - More than one formatter

Tags: protractor, cucumber, formatter, allure, cucumberjs

Lately, I've implemented in my project allure-cucumberjs reporter. It working well but I've got also package which formats the logs during test execution ([cucumber-pretty](https://github.com/kozhevnikov/cucumber-pretty)). Now, while I provide Allure reporter to cucumberOpts.format together with cucumber-pretty, the 2nd one doesn't want to work.

What I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "allure-cucumberjs": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "cucumber-pretty": "^6.0.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.2.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
  },
```

config.ts

```
 cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register',
    format: [
        'json:results/results.json',
        'node_modules/cucumber-pretty',
        'reporter/reporter.ts',
        'rerun:@rerun.txt',
    ],
    require: ['../e2e/steps/*.ts', '../e2e/support/*.ts', '../support/*.ts'],
    strict: true,
    tags: '',
  }
```

If I remove the 'reporter/reporter.ts' from the above config file, then pretty plugin works well.

Is that a bug, that Allure overrides somehow and disable other formatter? Or it should work in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

In `format` section you can include several reporters, but only one of them can output to stdout. This is a limitation of cucumber API.
You need to point Allure reporter to a dummy file: `reporter/reporter.ts:dummy.txt`.